# Tracking views of Story Maps on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

Is there a way to track how much traffic (how many views) an ArcGIS Online (by Esri) story map gets?

Google analytics type thing?

Comment: That's a tough one to answer have you consider keyhole solutions?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Why not Google analytics?  You could always generate your own tracking if you have access to server-side.  Maybe something like: http://www.liesdamnedlies.com/2014/02/building-your-own-web-analytics-system-using-big-data-tools.html or http://blogs.splunk.com/2013/10/17/still-using-3rd-party-web-analytics-providers-build-your-own-using-splunk/.  I skimmed them, but the idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new service precisely for map analytics, http://get.maptiks.com/maptiks-v1/.
Currently only supports Google Maps, Leaflet and Open Layers, but says ESRI is coming soon.